# Wordpress hook to add content under title or post status buttons on edit.php

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm looking to add some content above the wp_list_table for a custom post type. I have custom bulk actions and filters but would like to add some further content to this header area. I cant seem to find a hook that will get me into the header. The only one I can seem to find is 'all_admin_notices' which is above the page title so not optimal.

Anywhere either below the title, below the post status buttons or even under the bulk action / filters will do.

Is this possible? If so what hook am I looking at?.

Image link below. Area highlighted in red is what I'm trying to achieve.

http://indi-media.com/stackoverflow/Example.jpg

Thanks Guys.

Comment: You could extend the wp table class and do it that way

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-a-subtitle-to-wordpress-post-and-page-titles/

Comment: @Len_D that was to create a custom meta field in your create post screen. What i'm looking for is the admin area where the posts are listed as a table. Thanks for looking anyway.@andyroo at this point I think that's what I'm going to have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it probalby isnt possible without a hacky jquery approach or extending the wp table class which I'm not keen on doing. The only real way to do it is to construct the page and tables etc yourself.

Thanks for the pointers anyway guys.